# Agile Web Development with Rails 3rd Edition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

it is showing me following error when i m opening http://localhost:3000/store

> **We're sorry, but something went wrong.
>
> We've been notified about this issue
>   and we'll take a look at it shortly.**

do anyone knows why it is showing me that error?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617525/how-to-resolve-something-went-wrong-error-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the `development.log` file inside your log directory, it should give you a better clue.

Comment: in chapter 9: Add Ajax i make some changes in development.log file as per written in book. let me check thanks

Comment: i m not getting ny clue how to resolve this problem

i remember one thing that when i open development.log first time i remain it open and when i try to close it ask me to save changes and i clicked yes.

so can u plese help me how to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Close your log file, then open your website again, and then open the log file, you should see an error description in there.

Comment: yes it is showing me error started with the following.

/!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Sat Oct 24 18:06:22 +0500 2009
  Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  D:/RubyOnRails/rails_apps/work/depot/app/helpers/store_helper.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '}'
 def hidden_div_if(condition, attributes = {), &block)
                                             ^
D:/RubyOnRails/rails_apps/work/depot/app/helpers/store_helper.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting $end....

Comment: ok i have resolved this problem thnks alot my friend :)

i want to know one more thing u told me before also tell me plese how to update a remote form i m wrting the code u please tell me how what code should i add to update it.

<% form_remote_tag :url => { :action => 'add_to_cart', :id => product } do %>
   <%= submit_tag "Add to Cart" %>

Comment: Since this is a separate question, you should ask a new question describing what you tried and what's not working.

Comment: i have that question already in a separate question few days ago here is its link n u replied to that question to use update tag for it but i don't know it syntax please visit the link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585138/agile-web-development-with-rails-ajax